# How TO Call JSON Result in Controller From Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a simple JSON in custom module

```
 public JsonResult GetStatus()
    {

        return Json(new { Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

And using a button click I supposed to call this JSON using AJAX

```
function GetStatus() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/OrchardLocal/Info/GetStatus',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: "true",
        cache: "true",
        success: function (response) {

        }
    });

}
```

But Orchard prompted me an error saying that it's an invalid controller

How Do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you mapped the routes for your controller? You can create correct urls with the razor url helper: `@Url.Action("GetStatus", "Info", new { Area = "MyModuleArea")`

Comment: THank you sir, It worked like a charm :)